# FindFirstPartition unhandled exception in wince6.0

Tags: c++, c, windows-ce

I am trying to get the file system type and I am getting an unhandled exception for a 64GB usb exFAT USB stick with 0 bytes space left.

```
    HANDLE handle = OpenStore(wPath);
    if(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        PARTINFO lPartInfo;

        HANDLE handlePartInfo = FindFirstPartition(
                handle,
                &lPartInfo
        );//exception here my guess!!

        if(handlePartInfo != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {



            res = (char *) malloc(8);



            if(lPartInfo.bPartType == PART_DOS2_FAT || lPartInfo.bPartType == PART_DOS3_FAT ||
                    lPartInfo.bPartType == PART_DOS4_FAT || lPartInfo.bPartType == PART_DOS32 )
            {

                strcpy(res,"vfat");
            }
            else
            {
                strcpy(res,"invalid");
            }



        }
    }
```

Can somebody tell me why I am getting this exception and how to fix this?

Comment: You never set the `cbSize` member of your [**`PARTINFO`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914760.aspx) structure to `sizeof(PARTINFO)` before your invocation of `FindFirstPartition`

Comment: I added the following line - lPartInfo.cbSize = sizeof(PARTINFO); but can you shortly tell me why it is required. How it is linked to the crash??

Comment: Were I to guess, their API starts out by zero-filling the structure, and it uses that field-member value to perform the operation. Without initialization, it is *indeterminate* and thus undefined behavior to even *eval* much-less *use*. But the better question is, *did it address your problem??*

Comment: I cannot tell currently whether the problem is fixed because it needs a build to check it. One more question in bPartType types defined in msdn website I cannot see any 64bit exFAT identifier. Am I missing something in the "if" check for the bPartType in the code above??

Comment: There are multiple values, some of them apparently not listed in `storemgr.h` The documentation on `PARTINFO` lists most of them (so they say).

Comment: You should also close the handle returned by FindFirstPartition or you'll have a memory leak.